# Erro "Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset" no Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Eu utilizava a versão do WP 4.9.3, após fazer a atualização para a ultima versão que é a 5.0.3, começou a aparecer a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> "Warning: Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in /home/nfe/public_html/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php on line 445"

Gostaria de saber se alguém já teve o mesmo erro, se sim, como foi resolvido.
O erro aparece no seguinte código:

```
foreach ( (array) $l10n as $key => $value ) {
  if ( !is_scalar($value) )
    continue;
  $l10n[$key] = html_entity_decode( (string) $value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Comment: Como vamos saber oq tem no arquivo `/home/nfe/public_html/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php` e na linha `445`? [Poste seu código](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5484/45810)! ;)

Comment: Acabei esquecendo, ja postei o codigo do erro.

Comment: tente colocar no if is_scalar  `|| $key == "" ||$value == ""`